# Donating Windows 10 Laptop to a Student

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, factory-defaults

I can't seem to find information on my specific case. I've decided to donate a laptop to a smaller charity where it will be given straight to a high school or college student in need.

I've talked with an admin at the charity and the laptop will be given straight up to the student so they prefer me to have prior-cleaned/prepared the laptop.

The laptop had a failing hard drive, so I replaced it, and reinstalled windows 10, and MS office Home.

But in the installation process, windows required me to sign into my MS account.

I know about the "reset to factory settings" mode, but I do also want to make sure the student has access to MS office that is installed on it.

Is there a way to do a factory reset, but keep the MS office on it for the student?

If not, is there a way to make sure that I can remove my MS account information from the computer entirely?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not required to log into a Microsoft account when you install Windows 10, the option to create a local account does exist, but the solution is simple at this point.  Enable the built Administrator account and delete the account you created.  There are existing questions that answer how to install Windows 10 without creating an account linked to a Microsoft account

Comment: I don't use windows/ms products very often, but will that allow the student to use the office products from a different account? (i.e., are the office products tied to the account or computer?)

Comment: Also, the student doesn’t need your office license. They can literally get it almost free through school. They shouldn’t even be given your license, it’s not theirs and it’s against the license agreement. It doesn’t do them any good.

Comment: Depends if the license is connected to your Microsoft account, you didn’t make that clear, if it’s a Office 365 license it absolutely cannot be transferred to another student.  If you installed Office 365, remove it, and let the student worry about it

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I didn't know that.  I have no idea about the exact license. I think I'll go ahead and factory reset and the student should be able to either (a) use their own version or (b) use the student's version.